# ESP8266 and IFTTT

Tags: arduino, esp8266, ifttt

I am working on a simple device that alerts me when a button is pushed.  At this time I am just trying to get the ESP8266 to activate the webhook event on it's own.  It will connect to the wifi, but will not activate the event.  I don't know if I'm going about this the wrong way or not.  The http.Get() command returns back a -1.  How do I activate the webhook?  Any help is appreciated.  The code is below.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid="ATT2506";
const char* password = "XXXXXXXX";

int ledPin = 2;

void setup() {

  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Wifi connecting to ");
  Serial.println( ssid );

  WiFi.begin(ssid,password);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting");

  while( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ){
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");        
  }


  Serial.println();

  Serial.println("Wifi Connected Success!");
  Serial.print("NodeMCU IP Address : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP() );

  digitalWrite( ledPin , LOW);

}

void loop() {

  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    digitalWrite( ledPin , HIGH);
  }

  if (1==1) { //Check WiFi connection status

    HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient

    http.begin("https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/csalarm/with/key/XXXXXXXXXXX");  //Specify request destination
    int httpCode = http.GET(); //Send the request
    Serial.println(httpCode);

    if (httpCode > 0) { //Check the returning code

      String payload = http.getString();   //Get the request response payload
      Serial.println(1);                     //Print the response payload

    }

    http.end();   //Close connection

  }

  delay(30000);    //Send a request every 30 seconds
}
```

Comment: Assuming you're using the library I think you are, [the HTTPClient header](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoHttpClient/blob/master/src/HttpClient.h) indicates that a -1 response means you failed to reach the destination URL.  I will flag a bit of suspicion at the line `if (1==1) { //Check WiFi connection status` which will always evaluate to true, regardless of connection status.  Check to make sure you're connected and that your device isn't being blocked by a firewall on the wireless endpoint or something.

Comment: To use HTTPS you need to provide a fingerprint.

Comment: Thanks!!!.  I changed it to http:// instead and it worked.  I'm not familiar with the difference so I'll do some research.